# Write the code to display first 50 numbers of the series 3,7,16,35

Tags: java

Write the code to display first 50 numbers of the series: 3,7,16,35.....
I have done the coding for this question but the output shows only "35" when i click the display button . please help .. (i need to do this question using do-while loop)
Here is the coding.....

```
private void displayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
   int a=3,count=1,c=1;
   do
   {
       resulttf.setText(a+",");
       a=(2*a)+c;
       c++;
       count++;
   }while(a<=50);
}
```

Comment: You're overwriting the contents of your field every time. You should build the content with a `StringBuilder` then display it at the end.

Comment: but sir ... our teacher didnt teach us about string builder .. so how can i add it ?

Comment: Let google be your teacher now. Google it

Comment: I can't understand. Your teacher is teaching you basic algorithm constructs like loops. You're not supposed to use StringBuilder yet because your teacher hasn't talked about yet. But you're supposed to use Swing to implement your homework? That's like needing to be able to pilot a Boeing 747 to go to elementary school.

Comment: ok .. but i dont knw wht it is actually ! ok tell me ...how to use it ..i hav just reached !! std ..and informatics is a new subject for me ..be kindly understand ..iam not getting the solution ..thats y iam asking

Comment: @user3747779: start by changing your keyboard. It seems like it can't type some vowels and uppercase letters anymore.

Comment: If you're using java8, using [`StringJoiner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) could be an interesting option.

Comment: resulttf is the name of the textfield

Answer (score 2):

You have to call:

```
resulttf.setText(resulttf.getText()+","+a);
```

Comment: thank you ...but its only displaying 3,7,16,35 . It doesnt display 50 numbers of the series

Comment: @user3747779: execute your algorithm on paper. At each iteration, write the new value of `a`, and then ask yourself why the loop stops.

Comment: @user3747779 you only run in the loop untio a is lower than 50 i think you have to change `while(a<=50);` to `while(counter<=50);`

Comment: i changed it ..and i got the result ..Thank you